# How to re-publish dead-letter PubSub messages with a filter and rate-limited?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-pubsub

When a large number of Pub/Sub messages have ended up in the dead-letter Topic/Subscription due to a transient issue / bug, we want to be able to re-publish these to the original Topic, to try again.

To ensure this is done in a controlled way we need to:

- Filter the messages by a message attribute
- Rate limit the publishing, eg to only publish one message every 50ms

The idea being that we can prioritise which messages are re-processed but trickle them in to avoid impacting new messages being published to the Topic.

I've looked at the Pub/Sub to Pub/Sub Dataflow template.  This provides the filtering I need, but not the rate-limiting.

I could write a console app, which pulls messages from the dead letter subscription, filters locally then re-publishes to the original topic.  But this seems to have various problems, eg if you NAck a message that does not match the filter, it will immediately be retried so will keep being pulled by the console app until all you get in a pull are messages you don't want.

Is there an out-of-box way to do this, which seems like a fairly common requirement?

---

Edit:
Just tested using Dataflow and the filtering doesn't behave as I'd hoped. Rather than just extracting messages which match the filter, and leaving the rest unacknowledged, it acknowledges all the messages.  In other words, you can only run the Dataflow once, and not several times to extract different groups of messages with different filters.

Comment: Does this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61650087/) help you?

Comment: Thanks @kiranmathew. It's a similar question, but doesn't address the filtering and rate-limiting that I need.

Comment: Can you take a look at this [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197906331) also.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way of implementing this using GCP functionality, so wrote a command-line utility to move messages, instead.

The utility has three commands:

- Move
- Filter
- Partition

`Move` pulls messages from a Subscription and re-publishes to a Topic. Optionally with a configurable delay between messages.

`Filter` pulls messages from a Subscription and applies a filter based on the message attributes. Those messages that match are re-published to a Topic. The ones that do not match are just acknowledged, so they will not be processed.

`Partition` is like `Filter` except that the messages that don't match the filter are published to a second Topic.

The idea is that you can create a number of temporary Topics, each with one Subscription, then use the commands to process the messages along between the Topics in a pipeline (of sorts) until you have the messages you want.  Then you can use `Move` to replay those messages back onto the original Topic.

For anyone looking to do the same, I used the .NET `Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1` Nuget package for the Subscriber and Publisher clients, and the `System.CommandLine` package for parsing arguments and giving help text to the user.